# ExtendedListView which is defined in another class is invisible

Tags: android, view

I'm currently trying to implement an ExtendedListView that uses an Adapter.
I'm implementing the View like this in an activity:

```
groupView = new GroupView((ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.groupView), getApplicationContext());
```

The constructor of GroupView looks like this:

```
public GroupView(ExpandableListView list, Context c)
{
    context = c;
    expandableListView = list;
    adapter = new GroupViewAdapter(context,
            new ArrayList<ParticipantGroup>(),
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<Participant>>());
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

The adapter looks like this:

```
public class GroupViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    private Context                         context;
    private ArrayList<ParticipantGroup>     groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Participant>>   children;

    public GroupViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ParticipantGroup> groups,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Participant>> children)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.children = children;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the complete structure (Map of groups with a list of participants
     * each) and draws it
     */
    public void updateView()
    {   
        Map<String, ParticipantGroup> groupMap = GroupManager.getInstance()
                .getGroups();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ParticipantGroup> entry : groupMap.entrySet())
        {
            String groupName = entry.getKey();
            ParticipantGroup group = entry.getValue();

            if(!groups.contains(group)) //In case the group does not exist yet, it gets created
            {
                groups.add(group);
            }
            int index = groups.indexOf(group);
            if (children.size() < index + 1) {
                children.add(new ArrayList<Participant>());
            }
            ArrayList<Participant> participants = group.getParticipants();
            Iterator<Participant> itr = participants.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                children.get(index).add(itr.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When going trough the adapter I see the groups get added where they're supposed to, but I can't actually see anything in the emulator. It's just a white background. Can you tell me what I'm missing to actually make this visible?

**Edit**: Okay, it was a simple `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` that was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was a simple `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` that was missing (After calling `updateView()`)